# Integral maximization inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, symmetric-matrices

Is it true that for all symmetric $n \times n$ matrix, $(a_{ij})$, such that for $x \in \{\pm 1\}^n$
$$
\sum_{ij} a_{ij} x_i x_j \leq 1
$$
there exists a universal constant such that 
$$
\sum_{ij} a_{ij} x_i y_j \leq C
$$
for all $x, y \in \{\pm 1\}^n$ .  I tried to use the polarization identity
$$
\langle Ax, y\rangle = \langle Au, u\rangle - \langle Av, v \rangle
$$
where $u = (x+y)/2$ and $ v = (x-y)/2$.  However, as $x$ and $y$ vary over $\pm 1$ vectors, $u$ and $v$ can be vectors in $\{\pm 1, 0\}$.

Comment: What is preventing you from declaring $C:=\sum_{ij}|a_{ij}|$?

Comment: I want a C independent of the matrix $(a_{ij})$ and the dimension $n$.

Comment: This is related to Grothendieck's inequality. You should check its proof.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. For any $A$ there is a constant such that the sum is bounded above, This is because the set of $(x,y)$ is compact and the function $\sum a_{ij} x_i y_j $ is continuous. It does not depend on the $\le 1$ condition.

Comment: Yes, that is clear.  I want a universal constant, independent of A.

Answer (score 1):

No, e.g. $x^T\pmatrix{n\\ &-n}x\equiv0$ for every $\{-1,1\}$-vector $x$, but $(1,1)\pmatrix{n\\ &-n}\pmatrix{1\\ -1}=2n$ is unbounded.